# how to make `mkfs.ext4 /dev/block/sda1` quickly?

Tags: linux, android, mkfs

I develop an application on Android, need to manage the disk, my program is root permission to run in the background of Android.One problem is that formatting disk partitions is so slow that it takes three hours to complete formatting on a `4TB` disk.The steps in my format are:

1. delete all partition
2. `parted -s /dev/block/sda mklabel gpt`
3. `parted -s /dev/block/sda mkparted ext2 0% 100%`
4. `mkfs.ext4 -F -b 4096 /dev/block/sda1`

Step 4 was slow when performing the above steps, so I replaced step 4 with:
`mkfs.ext4 -T lagerfile -F /dev/block/sda1` or `mkfs.ext4 -F -b 4194304 /dev/block/sda1`
but still slow.
So what's a faster way?
Thank you!

Comment: Since *lazx_journal_init* is default, have you tried to create the filesystem without a journal in the first place? `mkfs.ext4 .... -O "^has_journal" ... `.

Comment: As formatting a disk is always going to take a long time, I think your options are limited to getting a faster disk, and performing this operation on another machine (with a faster controller).

Comment: I don't have a 4TB drive but I have a 4TB sparse file and creating an ext4 FS on top of it makes mke2fs write just 59MB of data. This is not that much to think about it. Maybe it involves a lot of seeking that's why the operation is slow for you.

Comment: Try using the eatmydata utility ( https://github.com/stewartsmith/libeatmydata ) which disables data syncing and could make this operation lightning fast.

Answer (score 1):

Initializing an ext4 file system usually doesn't take very long, especially not considering the complexity of data structure being created! I'd however expect it to be much less than 100 MB of actual data written.
**Three hours is unreasonably long**; I've not once seen a mkfs.extX take this long; top of my head, 10 years ago, 2TB took about 20 minutes, at most. And that was with hard drives that are slow by modern standards, and over a SATA1 link that is slow by modern standards.
This probably means there's something wrong with your storage device, or the way it's connected. Check `dmesg -Hwx` and `journalctl -xef` for any error that appears during formatting.

---

**In the unlikely case hardware is fine, or you're accessing your hard drive over USB1.1 or it's actually a very massive stack of floppy drives emulating a SATA drive, or something:**

So, maybe your android tooling is oooooold. In that case, a) update your e2fsprogs (I have 1.46.3, you should have at least 1.45, which came out 2.5 years ago), which will give you faster results, or b) if that's not possible, try `mkfs.ext4 -E lazy_itable_init=1 -E lazy_journal_init=1`; but: that just shifts the time you spend on mkfs.ext4 to its first mount. There's no free lunch!

If your kernel has more file system support built in, you could also try other file systems. XFS is known for its fast creation, and might be good for your use case.